# Query problem-getting wrong result when a condition or a set of data included

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have bug in my query, but I have no idea what happen.
So there is 3 tables.

table 1

```
name   grade  min  max
a
b
c
d
e
```

table 2

```
fullname   name  min   max
a          a123  1     10
bbbb       b     2     20
c          cccc  3     30
d          dd    1     10
E          Ed    2     20
```

table 3

```
value    grade
25        A
15        B
5         C
```

my goal is using name, show the grade of the name( the max > value in table 3).

for example, c has 30 in max, it should have A grade, instead of B and C.

Also,  the name usually is the fullname in table 2, but sometime it is  name in the table2(like b)(here is one of bugs). That's how the table look like, I can't change it.

if I am not include the checking `table 1.name = table 2.name` . no bug at all, but cannot get grade for b

if i include the `table 1.name = table 2.name`.then, it has problem

for the query of matching the grade, it is like(assume get the min and max from table 2 before)

```
update table1
set table1.grade = table3.grade
from table1 inner join table3 
on table1.max > table3.value
```

All the cases are include the checking  `table 1.name = table 2.name`

case 1:
the grade will equal = C for all data if there is some data inlcude.

for example, in table1, if I am not include E, then everything is fine.

but if I include E, will get C grade for all records.

case 2:
if I run the query for all data at the same time, the result goes wrong.
it work fine if I update the record one by one.,
for example, i add one more condition in update query

```
update table1
set table1.grade = table3.grade
from table1 inner join table3 
on table1.max > table3.value and fullname='c'
```

after getting wrong result, i add the condition and run it again,
then c will get grade 'A' instead of 'C'. but if I remove the condition and run the query again.
c will get grade 'C' again.

case 3:
there is no problem when I only run the set of data that will cause case 1 problem independently. 
but if I put the data together, It cases problem.

That is all cases. I don't know what cause the problem. Please help

The result should be:
table 1

```
name   grade  min  max
a        C     1    10
b        B     2    20
c        A     3    30
d        C     1    10
e        B     2    20
```

If I remove `table1.name = table2.name`, result will be

table 1

```
name   grade  min  max
a        C     1    10
b       null  null  null
c        A     3    30
d        C     1    10
e        B     2    20
```

with `table1.name = table2.name`, result will be

table 1

```
name   grade  min  max
a        C     1    10
b        C     2    20
c        C     3    30
d        C     1    10
e        C     2    20
```

with `table1.name = table2.name` but remove e , result will be

table 1

```
name   grade  min  max
a        C     1    10
b        B     2    20
c        A     3    30
d        C     1    10
```

with `table1.name = table2.name` but only for e,result will be

```
name   grade  min  max
e        B     2    20
```

those situation happen when I run the update query for whole table.
there is no problem with `table1.name = table2.name` if I update each row one by one.

Comment: How can you add `table1.name = table2.name` to the query, when you have no table2 in the query? And you definitely should have it there, as you can not calculate the result from table1 and table3 only.

Comment: What are you supposed to get, when you have the same name in more than one row in table2?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek  `table1.name = table2.name` is not in update query, before the update query, there is one more query getting mix and max into table1 from table 2. Yes, somehow the condition in different query cause the problem. There is no same name in table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, you should avoid the way you update the table. You should be carefull with joins on update. If you happen to have more than one value for the same row, the result is not deterministic. Better use this form:

```
update table1
set table1.grade = (SELECT TOP 1 table3.grade FROM table3
                    WHERE table3.value < table1.max
                    ORDER BY table3.value DESC)
```

Comment: can you provide the detail query using my case, I am not sure how to select one value for each row

Comment: @SamLI I made an update, I hope it does what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, It works. One more question, If I need to update multiple columns, I need to repeat the select statement for each column??

Comment: @SamLI You are right, this is how it works. If you need to update multiple rows in simmilar way, you may want to revert to the join form. If you do, just make sure you select only one row in the subquery you are joining. The join form is not bad, it is just less safe, so use it only when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the expected results but you may have traced the problem already: incorrect criteria.
Before doing an update, just try a select with the same criteria eg:

```
select * 
from table1 inner join table3 
on table1.max > table3.value
```

and see what you get.

Comment: I tried that before, the result will be there are rows for each row in table 1, like:" [c 'A'], [c 'B' ], [c 'C']., it looks fine, but if I use the same condition to update it, it come out [c 'C']. it should be  [c, 'A']